# After REST API call ,i have key/value pair in the below format ,I Need to extract just the specific value corresponding to the key

Tags: java, arrays, json, rest, talend

[image: jobdesign]
[image: output]

Option 1 :if i use the TALEND job i get the JSON results stored with backslashes in the JSON file for some reason(which is unparseable)

```
{"read":[{"Body":"{\"items\":[{\"executionId\":\"a0613a31-d16d-4c4d-9279-4564a86cdd44\",\"startTimestamp\":\"2021-09-15T22:30:26.854Z\",\"triggerTimestamp\":\"2021-09-15T22:30:27.209Z\",\"userId\":\"user1\",\"status\":\"dispatching\",\"runtime{\"type\":\"REMOTE_ENGINE_CLUSTER\"},\"executionStatus\":\"DISPATCHING_FLOW\"},{\"executionId\":\"49a56eb1-f3c7-4f26-9554-8fa88acde38b\",\"startTimestamp\":\"2021-09-15T22:29:15.999Z\",\"triggerTimestamp\":\"2021-09-15T22:29:16.447Z\",\"userId\":\"user1\",\"executionType\":\"MANUAL\",\"status\":\"dispatching\",\"runtime\":{\"type\":\"REMOTE_ENGINE_CLUSTER\"},\"executionStatus\":\"DISPATCHING_FLOW\"}],\"limit\":100,\"offset\":0,\"total\":2}","ERROR_CODE":null}]}
```

Option 2:Using the WEB URL:
After REST API call,i have the JSON results like:

**BODY**:*context.statusbody*

```
{
    "items": [{
            "executionId": "4f679c12-d8d7-4dd7-89d5-507a94503988",
            "startTimestamp": "2021-09-14T19:05:01.854Z",
            "triggerTimestamp": "2021-09-14T19:05:02.385Z",
            "userId": "user1",
            "taskId": "60b7f6d31c6e394de0163d35",
            "status": "dispatching",
            "runtime": {
                "type": "REMOTE_ENGINE_CLUSTER"
            },
            "executionStatus": "DISPATCHING_FLOW"
        },
        {
            "executionId": "4f40b04c-1ac1-42ea-9a36-7c25b1b17fe8",
            "startTimestamp": "2021-09-14T19:00:24.769Z",
            "triggerTimestamp": "2021-09-14T19:00:25.122Z",
            "userId": "user1",
            "taskId": "60b7f6d31c6e394de0163d35",
            "executionType": "SCHEDULED",
            "status": "dispatching",
            "runtime": {
                "type": "REMOTE_ENGINE_CLUSTER"
            },
            "executionStatus": "DISPATCHING_FLOW"
        }
    ],
    "limit": 100,
    "offset": 0,
    "total": 2
}
```

From this i just need to extract the executionID and triggerTimestamp for each iteration and store in a global variable

In my grayed out tjava3 i am using global variable as:

```
  context.testexecutionID=((String)globalMap.get("executionID"));
  context.triggerTimestamp=((String)globalMap.get("triggerTimestamp"));
     context.executionID=context.testexecutionID.substring(5, context.testexecutionID.lastIndexOf("\"")-3);
  context.triggerTime=context.triggerTimestamp.substring(5, context.triggerTimestamp.lastIndexOf("\"")-3);
```

Comment: I copy pasted the JSON string into https://jsonlint.com/, this is not a valid JSON string. Please provide a valid JSON string

Comment: as @Bentaye mentionned this is not a valide JSON you have provided

Comment: My bad,maybe some strings were missing,i have fixed it and now its an valid JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@sarah Based on your valid JSON you added in your edit .

i suggest you to add after tRest to add tExtractJSONFields component paremetred as such :

[image]

Job Design should be in first test :

tRest -> tExtractJSONFields -> tLogRow .

If extraction is good . Second test you have to see my previous my first answer to get global Variables .

Comment: I am facing one peculiar issue now,that
executionID                                                                                                                     |triggerTimestamp                                                                            
|["[\"957510f7-f516-40ec-a6cc-29d6a9d93a1a\",\"78a18000-e8ea-44a9-a970-434c3135aac3\",\"7effc15a-4863-4981-b1c3-a0cffe35dfb7\"]"]|["[\"2021-10-15T00:21:02.392Z\",\"2021-10-15T00:21:01.589Z\",\"2021-10-15T00:21:01.142Z\"]"]|
If there are multiple values its not iterating and storing everything in one executionID

Comment: Is there a way to split it before i use them in the downstream tjava component individually?
like executionID:
957510f7-f516-40ec-a6cc-29d6a9d93a1a
78a18000-e8ea-44a9-a970-434c3135aac3
7effc15a-4863-4981-b1c3-a0cffe35dfb7
i am not sure how to extract them since they are all coupled in an single array parameter and i want to use them like iterating for every loop if there are multiple tasks available.Please suggest as i have added the latest job design to the question

Comment: In my grayed out tjava3 i am using global variable as:

     context.executionID=context.testexecutionID.substring(5, context.testexecutionID.lastIndexOf("\"")-3);

I want to split it individually for every iteration and do the calculation for each executionID and triggertimestamp separately for each task,since there are multiple i am getting an unparseable data error.

Comment: maybe using   a tNormlize  and add a comma separator . Other wise , if it didn't help open new topic with job design and desired output .

Comment: so job design would be : tfixedInput -> tnormlize (comma seperator) -> tlog

Comment: That was an wonderful suggestion,i was able to have them split but as you can see from the updated job design above i have 2 columns(executionID,triggerTimestamp) i would want to split and have them together and use in tjava3 in the context variables

Comment: The problem here is i can only split one column using tnormalize at a time and i want to have them stored in context.executionID corresponding to the task's triggertime in context.triggerTimestamp like every iteration,is there an effective way to handle such a way?for every loop rather than using coding

Comment: Maybe a treplicate would do the job .

Comment: Tfixedinput->treplicate ->main link ->tnormlize->tlog   . And for the other main just do same

Comment: I did something like the updated job design above based on the recommendation,seems like we're almost there but not precisely i am getting duplicates(repeated) for executionID for the corresponding triggertime  column ,i would essentially would want the pair of values to be stored into a context variable in tjava which i can use for each iteration to do the calculation or computation thereon

Comment: These are the context variables i will be using to store in input parameters based on the results obtained from tlogrow3:
 context.testexecutionID=((String)globalMap.get("executionID"));
context.triggerTimestamp=((String)globalMap.get("triggerTimestamp"));
     context.executionID=context.testexecutionID.substring(5, context.testexecutionID.lastIndexOf("\"")-3);
  context.triggerTime=context.triggerTimestamp.substring(5, context.triggerTimestamp.lastIndexOf("\"")-3);

Comment: I have created a new question thread with the precise and clear information pointing to the last piece which does not seem to align as per the expectations.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69651818/unable-to-normalize-the-results-using-restapi-call-in-tlogrow
Appreciate if you could take a look

Answer (score 1):

Okey , Json i Used for your case to do your requirement :

Note That your Json is not Valid

```json
{
    "items": [{
        "executionId": "6e5fa777-9ede-42b9-b862-03b4b1b12375",
        "startTimestamp": "2021-09-15T05:59:40.599Z",
        "triggerTimestamp": "2021-09-15T05:59:41.006Z",
        "userId": "user"
    }],
    "limit ": 100,
    "offset ": 0,
    "total ": 2
}
```

Without knowing your job design i just got the output that is posted right here .

My job design is as such :

[image]

**Important !**:   your tFileInputJson should  be like this to get the 2 fields

Same configuration if your want to used tExtractJSONFields .

[image]

to Stock your Global Variables :

[image]

to get the globalVariables easy way is to use tfixedFlowInput :

[image]

Output :

[image]

Comment: The job design is spectacular ,but the catch here is how to capture the  RESPONSE Body results from the REST API call into the JSON file?
It does not seem to fit the ideal format and instead gives something like this when i try to use tfileoutputjson after the trest call.I have added the updated job design to the question along with the json results.Appreciate your help

Comment: I have added the PART A to the question wherein i need to convert the JSON into the readable format and extract the executionID from part A to utilize in part B(separate job flow/design) to call tRest component again with dynamic executionID to terminate the specific execution/job

Comment: @sarah you have to add a textractJsonFields after tRest